# Who put the skew in my Skittles? Have there been studies as to which candy has a fairly uniform distribution of flavors?

Tags: secondary-education, primary-education, statistics

Since the beginning of time, candy has been used to illustrate the principles of distributions in early lessons on statistics.

[A recent informal study](http://www.csis.ysu.edu/~chang/student_proj/S3743_s02/s3743s02Measel.pdf) seems to indicate that the flavors of Skittles are not uniformly distributed.  While it would be a great exercise for more advanced students to ascertain the extent to which a given bag is distributed evenly, it does not serve as hefty a purpose in the very early stages of learning.

Have any educators or statisticians systematically studied different varieties and brands of candy expressly for their pedagogical value in primary- and secondary-level statistics?

Comment: While the title was a bit tongue-in-cheek, I am asking this in earnest.

Comment: Have you already searched for any? E.g., http://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0,33&q=skittles+statistics

Comment: There are quite a few articles on using them as a method in the classroom, but I'm more interested in whether they are a useful model.

Comment: Have you approached the manufacturer?

Comment: I've done this informally for a brand of colored candy called Nips. (I did this for an undergraduate class in statistics.) I don't know their manufacturing color distribution, but for the 36 packages I opened (having 432 pieces), those with "delicious" colors (red 82, orange 81, yellow 62) outnumber those with "non-delicious" colors (violet 59, dark blue 52, light blue 51, green 45).

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche While I have accepted the M&Ms answer, I think that this may be good as an additional answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(Sorry if my answer is as offensive as responding to a question about Coca-Cola with data about Pepsi!)

There are certainly some lesson plans around looking at statistics for **M&M colors**.

For example, see Supplemental Activity S3.3 from COMAP's "Mathematics: Modeling our World" [**here**](http://www.comap.com/highschool/projects/mmow/assets/DOSWIN/Course3/Unit3/Resources/U3SUPPL.PDF). COMAP (COnsortium for Mathematics and its APplications) is my general go-to for modeling related activities; for example, see the discussion of a different sugary item in my **[MESE post](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/1558/262)** on cake-cutting.

Another brief [**write-up**](http://www.rci.rutgers.edu/~mmm431/quant_methods_F13/MnMs_web_exercise.pdf) that I saw online recommended two other sources. One of these sources includes a classroom activity and has 'teaching' as a keyword; it is entitled: [**Testing Colour Proportions of M&Ms**](http://www.rsscse-edu.org.uk/tsj/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/johnson4.pdf). The other source, [**The Mysterious Case of the Blue M&M's**](http://psoup.math.wisc.edu/pub/mm/fricker.pdf), recommends the following:

[image]

The article is from 1996, so I'm not sure if this "teaching device" is still available (though I suppose you could call and ask). You might also look up the (Landwehr et al, 1987) source mentioned at the end. Googling did not lead me to that particular one-sheet guide, though I did find yet another **[M&M project](http://courses.washington.edu/stats315/newpage1.htm)** on the subject described online.

Lastly, you might download [**this thesis**](https://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~iase/publications/dissertations/00.Meletiou.Dissertation.pdf) and search for mentions of M&Ms (e.g., p. 33, p. 243).

In response to your comment ("There are quite a few articles on using them as a method in the classroom, but I'm more interested in whether they are a useful model") I would say there are enough different items online to put something of interest together.

Comment: This is fantastic! No, I'm not as particular about my teaching candy as I am about my cola.