# Unconstrained/Constrained optimization real life example

Tags: calculus, exercises

I am in charge of some practice lesson for Calculus II.
I have to show how to apply the theory for unconstrained optimization (mainly Hessian analysis) and constrained optimization (Lagrange multipliers).

I'd like to use functions and boundaries taken from the real world. These examples must be easy and solvable and they should appear 'not-too-boring' to students.

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: For "real life" example of undergraduate math topics (and high school math topics too) try COMAP https://www.comap.com

Comment: By "real world", will you accept examples that are merely *potentially* real (involving believable scenarios and real objects), or do you want problems that someone got paid to solve?

Comment: @Nick I'm interested in the first case.. Problems should be easy to solve for undergrad students: they have to be believable but not effectively realistic..

Comment: See also https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/1550/optimization-problems-that-todays-students-might-actually-encounter?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

Typical constrained optimization (useful to "get it") is asking for the rectangle of largest area that can be enclosed in a fence of given length. Sure, it can be reduced to one-dimensional, but leave that option out. Or ask for the largest volume box with given surface area.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few examples in Physics. [Lagrangian Mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_mechanics)

Comment: True, but quite a bit too sophisticated for beginners.